# How to properly aggregate?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, aggregate

I have a table for logs with over 6 million records. I want a query that shows me all the occurrences where the `src` goes to the same destination/port.

I tried this:

```
SELECT src, dst, dstport, COUNT(src) AS Hits 
FROM logs  
GROUP BY src 
ORDER BY Hits DESC;
```

Not sure that this query is giving me exactly what I want. Additionally, what is the best way to exclude specific port? Say `dstport = 53`?

I would like the to show each time each src reached the same dst & dstport while keeping count of the occurances. Say src 10.110.0.10 reached dst 10.2.9.124:53 2,345,568 times & also reached 192.168.9.18:80 174 times ; then the result would look like:
 Example:

`+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| src             | dst             | dstport | Hist    |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| 10.110.0.10     | 10.2.9.124      |      53 | 2345568 |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| 10.110.0.10     | 192.168.9.18    |      80 |     174 |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---------+`

However with the query above I am getting this results:

`+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| src             | dst             | dstport | Hist    |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| 10.110.0.10     | 10.2.9.124      |      53 | 1443780 |
| 10.110.0.10     | 192.168.9.124   |      53 | 1402210 |
| 10.192.31.23    | 10.192.1.120    |    8082 |  319507 |
| 10.192.31.19    | 10.192.1.186    |    8081 |  319203 |
| 192.168.31.131  | 192.168.31.130  |      80 |  290818 |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---------+`

Comment: Doesn't seem entirely clear what the result is supposed to be. Could you add a data sample and the expected result for it to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Your result seems fine to me - there's no dups of either src or dst - which is what I would expect. Perhaps you could show us some  DDL (SHOW CREATE TABLE...) and DML (INSERT INTO log VALUES(...)) - or an SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see everything with aggregation, you could do this

```
SELECT src,CONCAT(dst,':',dstport) dsp_port,COUNT(1) hits
FROM logs
GROUP BY src,dsp_port;
```

To see subtotals

```
SELECT
    IF
    (
        ISNULL(src)=1,
        'Total',
        IF
        (
            ISNULL(dst_port)=1,
            CONCAT(src,' Total'),
            CONCAT(src,' ',dst_port)
        )
    ) Statistic,hits
FROM
(
    SELECT src,CONCAT(dst,':',dstport) dst_port,COUNT(1) hits
    FROM logs
    GROUP BY src,dst_port
    WITH ROLLUP
) A;
```

Using your sample data

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS rob_d;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE rob_d;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE rob_d
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE logs
    -> (
    ->     src CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    ->     dst CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    ->     dstport  INT NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO logs (src,dst,dstport) VALUES
    -> ('10.110.0.10',   '10.2.9.124'    ,53),
    -> ('10.110.0.10',   '192.168.9.124' ,53),
    -> ('10.192.31.23',  '10.192.1.120'  ,8082),
    -> ('10.192.31.19',  '10.192.1.186'  ,8081),
    -> ('192.168.31.131','192.168.31.130',80);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM logs;
+----------------+----------------+---------+
| src            | dst            | dstport |
+----------------+----------------+---------+
| 10.110.0.10    | 10.2.9.124     |      53 |
| 10.110.0.10    | 192.168.9.124  |      53 |
| 10.192.31.23   | 10.192.1.120   |    8082 |
| 10.192.31.19   | 10.192.1.186   |    8081 |
| 192.168.31.131 | 192.168.31.130 |      80 |
+----------------+----------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the query's output

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     IF
    ->     (
    ->         ISNULL(src)=1,
    ->         'Total',
    ->         IF
    ->         (
    ->             ISNULL(dst_port)=1,
    ->             CONCAT(src,' Total'),
    ->             CONCAT(src,' ',dst_port)
    ->         )
    ->     ) Statistic,hits
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT src,CONCAT(dst,':',dstport) dst_port,COUNT(1) hits
    ->     FROM logs
    ->     GROUP BY src,dst_port
    ->     WITH ROLLUP
    -> ) A;
+----------------------------------+------+
| Statistic                        | hits |
+----------------------------------+------+
| 10.110.0.10 10.2.9.124:53        |    1 |
| 10.110.0.10 192.168.9.124:53     |    1 |
| 10.110.0.10 Total                |    2 |
| 10.192.31.19 10.192.1.186:8081   |    1 |
| 10.192.31.19 Total               |    1 |
| 10.192.31.23 10.192.1.120:8082   |    1 |
| 10.192.31.23 Total               |    1 |
| 192.168.31.131 192.168.31.130:80 |    1 |
| 192.168.31.131 Total             |    1 |
| Total                            |    5 |
+----------------------------------+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks Ronaldo. How can I get it to display the src, dst, dstport and the hits? Right now I have only the src and hits.